# "Letter" tokenizer and "word_delimiter" filter not working with underscores

Tags: elasticsearch

I built an ElasticSearch index using a custom analyzer which uses `letter` tokenizer and `lower_case` and `word_delimiter` token filters. Then I tried searching for documents containing underscore-separated sub-words, e.g. `abc_xyz`, using only one of the sub-words, e.g. `abc`, but it didn't come back with any result. When I tried the full-word, i.e. `abc_xyz`, it did find the document.

Then I changed the document to have dash-separated sub-words instead, e.g. `abc-xyz` and tried to search by sub-words again and it worked.

To try to understand what is going on, I thought I would check the terms generated for my documents using `_termvector` service, and the result was identical for both, the underscore-separated sub-words and the dash-separated sub-words, so really I expect the result of searching to be identical in both cases.

Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

If it helps, this is the settings I used for my index:

```
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
          "cmt_value_analyzer": {
            "tokenizer": "letter",
            "filter": [
              "lowercase",
              "my_filter"
            ],
            "type": "custom"
          }
        },
        "filter": {
          "my_filter": {
            "type": "word_delimiter"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "alertmodel": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "analyzer": "cmt_value_analyzer",
          "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets_payloads",
          "type": "string"
        },
        "productId": {
          "type": "double"
        },
        "productName": {
          "analyzer": "cmt_value_analyzer",
          "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets_payloads",
          "type": "string"
        },
        "link": {
          "analyzer": "cmt_value_analyzer",
          "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets_payloads",
          "type": "string"
        },
        "updatedOn": {
          "type": "date"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: As I said above, I tried searching for sub-words like "abc", "xyz", and it worked if the document was "abc-xyz" but didn't when the document was "abc_xyz".

Comment: There are a lot of way of searching in ES. For example if you use query string by default it will search on _all field and that can cause mismatches. Thats the reason I asked for your method.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. I am simply using `/<index>/<type>/_search?q=<query>`, or sometimes without specifying the type.